# SSH Tunneling with a c library

Tags: c, ssh, portforwarding, tunnel, libssh

I am trying to use libssh library to open an SSH tunnel.

Basically, I need to reach a server through a tunnel. First, I would need to SSH to the gateway (I have already done this), then I would need to SSH from that host to the server:

[PC] -- `ssh user1@gateway` --> [gateway] -- `ssh www@server` --> [server]

The first ssh needs a password to reach the gateway but the second ssh is of a different user and it doesn't require a password.

I want to reach that server and execute a script, in this case, it's just a command: `ls -all`

I tried using `ssh_channel_open_forward()` but I don't know where to specify the 'user' plus it hangs when I use it. There aren't many examples to follow or that much of documentation.

Here is how I tried to reach a server through a bridge/tunnel :

```
int direct_forwarding(ssh_session session)
{
    ssh_channel channel;
    int rc = -1;
    int nbytes, nwritten;
    channel = ssh_channel_new(session);
    if (channel == NULL) {
        return rc;
    }
    printf("\n*********channel is created************\n");
    rc = ssh_channel_open_forward(channel, "server", 22, "gateway", 22);
    if (rc != SSH_OK)
    {
        ssh_channel_free(channel);
        return rc;
    }
    printf("\n*********channel is opened************\n");
    char *command = "ls -all";
    nbytes = strlen(command);
    nwritten = ssh_channel_write(channel, command, nbytes);
    if (nbytes != nwritten)
    {
        ssh_channel_free(channel);
        return SSH_ERROR;
    }
    printf("\n*********Write command is finished************\n");
    char buffer[256];
    nbytes = ssh_channel_read(channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    while (nbytes > 0)
    {
        printf("number of bytes read : %d\n", nbytes);
        if (write(1, buffer, nbytes) != (unsigned int)nbytes)
        {
            ssh_channel_close(channel);
            ssh_channel_free(channel);
            return SSH_ERROR;
        }
        nbytes = ssh_channel_read(channel, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    }

    if (nbytes < 0)
    {
        ssh_channel_close(channel);
        ssh_channel_free(channel);
        return SSH_ERROR;
    }
    ssh_channel_send_eof(channel);
    ssh_channel_close(channel);
    printf("\n*******************no errors*******************\n");
    ssh_channel_free(channel);
    return SSH_OK;
}
```

Is this possible in libssh?